# Service worker not loading all files in a specific server and system

Tags: reactjs, browser, service-worker, cachestorage

I am working on react js sketch tool which is enabled with service worker. Now in local environment and server offline is perfectly working while when we deployed into client server under nginx, only one system was able to access offline mode while any other system which access it is left with only 6 files in cache while i need about 15 files in total to load offline mode. Also in system which is not able to access, i could notice service worker is not activated after wait. I have tested it in edge, Firefox and chrome with similar issue. I am not exactly understanding what might be issue nor i am able to replicate the similar issue on my end. So any suggestions about how to tackle this

I tried changing code of service worker  which eventually is working fine in local but inspite any change i am not able to replicate issue. I just need all the 15 files to load in client system too. I just wanted to know if this is browser related issue or server related or code related